# SQL optimization for multiple tables (7) using MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have seven tables and when I execute the following sql query, it takes a long time to process the query and my system hangs while doing so.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    M.MerchantId, 
    M.MerchantName, 
    M.Image
FROM 
    CCodes as CC, 
    Merchants as M, 
    MemberStores as MS, 
    MemberCategories as MC, 
Categories as C, 
    MembersLogin as ML, 
    CategoryAndMerchant as CM
WHERE 
    (
        (
            M.MerchantId = MS.MerchantId 
        AND MS.MemberId = ML.Id
        ) 
        OR 
        (
            ML.Id = MC.MemberId 
        AND MC.CategoryId = C.Id 
        AND C.Id = CM.CategoryId 
        AND CM.MerchantId = M.MerchantId 
        AND CC.MerchantId = M.MerchantId
        )
    )
AND CC.Status = 1 
AND M.Status = 1 
AND C.Status = 1 
AND CC.Status = 1
AND EndDate BETWEEN '$todaysDate' AND '$endDate'        
AND ML.Id = $id             
ORDER BY EndDate asc
```

You may suppose any value for $todaysDate, $endDate and $id.
Please help me to optimize the query so that the execution time remains the least as much as possible.

Comment: could you run the query with EXPLAIN to see the execute path of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I note you print only information about table Merchants. So the other table instead apply a join try to use subqueries with not exists / exists as condition. Add some indexed, for example, on the field date as EndDate.

Why you put twice

```
AND CC.Status = 1
```

Tell me if it's ok after these advices

Comment: do you think a question like this asked on `Oct 28 '12 at 14:11` is still relevant?

Comment: I think there are questions unanswered, we can reduce this number. If I'm wrong, I will not answer more these old questions. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, the intention is good, but in this case your answer will hardly help the OP or be useful to any other user. Otherwise, what is the purpose?